# Bilateral filtering with cvSmooth() function

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

```
cvSmooth(img, dst, CV_BILATERAL, 3,3,0,0);
```

According to the function definition, it should work, but I am getting the same picture as the input without any smoothing effect. I don't understand why while other smoothing types(Gaussian, median, etc.) work finely.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How do you compare the images? BTW, OpenCV C api is **deprecated**

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your sigma values. Sigma1 determines how colors will interact within the kernel. Sigma2 determines weighting based on spatial distance. Sigma values of zero in a bilateral filter mean that you are using a spatial and color domain of zero, meaning no filtering is being performed.

Comment: `cvSmooth(img, dst, CV_BILATERAL, 10,20,10,20);`
I also tried in this way but there is no effect at output image.

Comment: There is still some misunderstanding. The window size has to be square for the bilateral filter. You are using 10,20. cvSmooth will only use the first size argument, so it is actually running a 10x10 kernel aperture. Your spatial sigma is 20, which is larger than the kernel. Depending on the bit depth of your input image the color sigma value may be too low to affect the image visibly. If the input is 8-bit try something like (img,dst,CV_BILATERAL,10,10,120,10).       Also it is worth noting that the cvSmooth function has been deprecated. You should probably use bilateralFilter() instead.